# Ordenar duas listas com base na ordem da primeira

Tags: python, array, lista

Vou dar um exemplo pois fica mais claro para explicar:

```
x = [7,5,9,4,2,3,8,1,10]
y = ['sete', 'cinco', 'nove', 'quatro', 'dois', 'tres', 'oito', 'um', 'seis', 'dez']
```

Preciso ordenar a lista `x`, de modo que `x[i] = y[i]`, ou seja, as listas devem ficar assim:

```
new_x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
new_y = ['um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis','sete', 'oito', 'nove', 'dez']
```

Exemplo:

```
x[5] = 3
y[5] = 'tres'
```

Após ordenar:

```
new_x[5] = 6
new_y[5] = 'seis'
```

Basicamente precisaria ordenar a segunda lista ao mesmo tempo que ordeno a primeira. De modo que os elementos sigam pareados.

Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Na sua lista `x` está faltando o número 6, mas pela descrição do problema, creio que foi erro de digitação...

Answer (score 2):

Uma alternativa é criar uma lista de índices, e ordenar estes índices de acordo com o respectivo valor em `x`.

Depois você usa estes índices para ordenar as listas:

```
x = [7, 5, 9, 4, 2, 3, 8, 1, 6, 10]
y = ['sete', 'cinco', 'nove', 'quatro', 'dois', 'tres', 'oito', 'um', 'seis', 'dez']

# ordene os índices em vez dos elementos em si
indices = list(range(len(x)))
indices.sort(key=lambda i: x[i]) # ordene os índices com relação ao seu respectivo valor em x

# crie as listas baseado na ordem dos índices
new_x = [x[i] for i in indices]
new_y = [y[i] for i in indices]

print(new_x) # [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
print(new_y) # ['um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'sete', 'oito', 'nove', 'dez']
```

`list(range(len(x)))` cria a lista com os índices (no caso, os números de zero até o tamanho de `x`).

A seguir, ordenamos os índices, usando como critério o respectivo valor na lista `x`. Após o `sort`, a lista `indices` será `[7, 4, 5, 3, 1, 8, 0, 6, 2, 9]`, o que quer dizer que `x[7]` é o primeiro elemento de `x` (quando este for ordenado), `x[4]` é o segundo, etc, e o mesmo vale para `y`.

Sendo assim, basta colocar as listas `x` e `y` na ordem indicada pela lista `indices`.

---

Outra forma de criar a lista de índices já ordenada seria:

```
indices = sorted(range(len(x)), key=lambda i: x[i])
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!! Ajudou muito!

Comment: @LucasVasques 
Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema.

Answer (score 1):

Tem a caminho da programação funcional utilizando as funções builtin [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#zip) para juntar as duas lista, [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#sorted) para ordenar essa junção e [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/functions.html#map) para aplicar uma função separadora da listas ordenadas:

```
x = [7, 5, 9, 4, 2, 3, 8, 1, 6, 10]
y = ['sete', 'cinco', 'nove', 'quatro', 'dois', 'tres', 'oito', 'um', 'seis', 'dez']

xy = zip(x, y)                               #Junta as duas listas numa lista d tuplas: [(7, 'sete'), (5, 'cinco'), (9, 'nove'), (4, 'quatro'), (2, 'dois'), (3, 'tres') (8, 'oito'), (1, 'um'), (6, 'seis'), (10, 'dez')] .

sorted_xy = sorted(xy, key= lambda t: t[0])  #Orderna xy com base no primeiro elemento de cada tupla.

new_x= list(map(lambda t: t[0], sorted_xy))  #Extrai o resultado da ordenação da lista x.
new_y= list(map(lambda t: t[1], sorted_xy))  #Extrai o resultado da ordenação da lista y.

print(new_x)
print(new_y)
```

Resultando:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
['um', 'dois', 'tres', 'quatro', 'cinco', 'seis', 'sete', 'oito', 'nove', 'dez']
```